# Invalid input syntax for integer, for column VARCHAR with unique index running on express

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, svelte

I have problem for method Post data with postgresql as running database , using express as backend and svelte as front end
I have sample data like below pictures, note that the database schema is already exists created using spring, so i was building frontend using svelte with working REST API from the existing database, all works fine for method GET which i was receiving all the data.

[data from express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGnZo.png)

[svelte form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibwLY.png)

i tried to post data to the server but there's an error -> `invalid input syntax for integer: "SS_3"`

Below is the code for the post method :

```
router.post('', async (req, res) => {
  const { label, subject_id, study_id, status_id, owner_id, oc_oid } = req.body
  const { rows } = await postgres.query('INSERT INTO s_02052020test.study_subject(label,subject_id,study_id,status_id,owner_id,oc_oid) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);', [label, subject_id, study_id, status_id, owner_id, oc_oid])
  res.json(rows)
});
```

SQL code for table study_subject :

```
CREATE  TABLE s_02052020test.study_subject ( 
study_subject_id     integer DEFAULT nextval('s_02052020test.study_subject_study_subject_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL ,
label                varchar(30)   ,
secondary_label      varchar(30)   ,
subject_id           integer   ,
study_id             integer   ,
status_id            integer   ,
enrollment_date      date   ,
date_created         timestamptz   ,
date_updated         timestamptz   ,
owner_id             integer   ,
update_id            integer   ,
oc_oid               varchar(40)  NOT NULL ,
time_zone            varchar(255) DEFAULT ''::character varying  ,
user_id              integer   ,
user_status_id       integer   ,
CONSTRAINT pk_study_subject PRIMARY KEY ( study_subject_id ),
CONSTRAINT uniq_study_subject_oid UNIQUE ( oc_oid ) );
```

how to resolve this problem? please any help/links to read/search would be very appreciated , thank you :)

Comment: You insert not integer value to integer. Please show pg table study_subject

Comment: the pg table study_subject oc_oid column is VARCHAR  @SMITRYTISHKIN

Comment: may be in js when you set value oc_oid convert to string?

Comment: already done that , using "SS_3" in svelte form , same error still came up

Comment: add integer interestingly came up error -> invalid input syntax for integer: ""